# Counting points on 2 sheets based on 4 possible cell values

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm making a roster of sorts and would like to award points to people's names when they attend events. For example, we use 4 possible responses; Attended, Late, Absent and AWOL. Essentially, Attended will award 2 points, Late will award 1, Absent 0 and AWOL will deduct 2.

We have a main "database" sheet with everyone's information and then a sheet with attendance. I'd like to use `QUERY(select where)` to determine the right name to add the points to.

I don't fully understand the Query function and its limitations which is why I thought I'd ask here as I'm sure most of you are 10x as knowledgable as I am with Google Sheets. I thought about just using `=if(A1='Second sheet'!A2)` etc. but remembered about the query function which is able to help automate this process much more.

This is where I'd like the points to be shown on the "Database" sheet.

[image: https://gyazo.com/2ee4511723c65f4f97a3029107c0fa61]

And this is the data on the "Attendance" sheet.

[image: https://gyazo.com/c58f7fbc97c0ec2ba96a15d79d7f280d]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", MMULT(IFERROR(
 SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C2:D, 
 "Attended", 2), 
 "Late",     1), 
 "AWOL",    -2)*1, 0), 
 TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C2:D))^0), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F8:F, Attendance!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]